# Random numbers in Python

Tags: python, random

I created the list with range numbers from -90 to 90. Now I need to make the random number from this list to appear in my question. Can anyone help me with that?
This is where I got so far:

```
latitude = [n for n in range(-90,90)]
record = latitude[random.randrange(-90,90)]
question =['lati','country']
questions = random.choice(question)

if questions == 'lati':
    resp = raw_input('Is Wroclaw north of ' + record)
```

When I tried to run this I received an error saying that i cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot concatenate a string and a number.  The best way to display it would be to use a format string, as follows:

```
resp = raw_input('Is Wroclaw north of %d' % record)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `str()` here, because `record` is an integer, so you should convert it to string first before concatenation:

```
resp = raw_input('Is Wroclaw north of ' + str(record))
```

or use string formatting:

```
raw_input('Is Wroclaw north of {0}'.format(record))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `record = random.randrange(-90,90)` without a list.
Or the next construstion if you really need a list.

```
random.choice([1,2,3])
```